# Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

i got a cross origin  error  executing my angular app

error is

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:52130/api/saveCandidate. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:52299' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

i'm tried to test my web api using postman i got error. it's given below

> {
>     "Message": "The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is not supported for this resource.",
>     "ExceptionMessage": "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Candidate' from content with media type 'multipart/form-data'.",
>     "ExceptionType": "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException",
>     "StackTrace": "   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync(HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
>   }

my web api is

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using TrackBoxAPI.Data.Model;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Dapper;
using System.Linq;

namespace TrackBoxAPI.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    [RoutePrefix("")]
    public class CandidateController :ApiController
    {
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/saveCandidate")]

    public string AddDetail(Candidate ct)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Constant.ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Insert_tblCandidate", con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CandidateId", ct.CandidateId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", ct.Name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", ct.Gender);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dob", ct.Dob);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mob", ct.Mob);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EntryDate", ct.EntryDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Note", ct.Note);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emial", ct.Emial);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", ct.Address);
        string CandidateId = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        // var 
        return CandidateId;
        //  return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, CandidateId);

    }
}
}
```

webApiConfig.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace TrackBoxAPI
{
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("* ", "* ", "* ");
        config.EnableCors(cors);



        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        //config.Routes.MapODataRoute("UltimaData", "OData", GenerateEDMModel());
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(
            new      System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/html")
  );
    }
   }
}
```

how can solve this error?

Comment: did you add the EnableCors also at the web.config file?

Answer (score 0):

**Add following section in startup.cs**

```
services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("YourPolicyName", p => p.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                                                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                                                                             .AllowAnyHeader()
                                                                             // Expose headers for new token in response.
                                                                             .WithExposedHeaders(" your customized header")
                                                                             ));
```

And Use **[EnableCors("YourPolicyName")]** attribute over your controller

Answer (score 0):

Also , In firewall configuration,enable **port** ,which you are using.